# How to add Jquery No Conflict in a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

in order to fix a jquery conflict between 2 different essential plugins installed in my joomla site, i have to put jQuery Into No-Conflict Mode in a .js file, how can I do this in this portions of code?

```js
$document->addScript(JURI::base().'plugins/content/avatar_slide_galleria/assets/js/galleria.min.js');
```

and in this one?

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Galleria.loadTheme('<?php echo JURI::base()."plugins/content/avatar_slide_galleria/assets/js/galleria.".$plgGalleria[$countPlg]->theme.".js"?>');
    Galleria.JURI = "<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>plugins/content/avatar_slide_galleria/assets/images/loader.gif";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```